# ¿Como hacer para evitar que un registro se inserte nuevamente usando ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net, webforms

Hola comunidad espero puedan ayudar con el siguiente problema ya que no encuentro la forma para hacerlo con ajax.

Mi problema es el siguiente:

Tengo un grid con una columna de botones llamada agregar, al dar clic a un botón este carga mis datos a una modal. Dentro de la modal esta otro botón llamado Aceptar que me permite agregar un registro a mi base de datos. Los datos no los tomo del grid en el boton paso directamente el procedimiento almacenado.

Ahora bien **¿Como puedo hacer para evitar insertar un registro doble vez sin cerrar la modal dentro del mismo ajax?**

Este es mi código ajax:

```js
 $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                datatype: "json",
                                url: "frmPersona.aspx/Agregar_Persona",
                                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                data: '{id_persona:"' + id_persona + '",nombre:"' + $("#txtNombre").val() + '",Ciudad:"' + $("#txtCiudad").val() + '"}',
                                cache: false,
                                success: function(data) {                                   
                                    $("#popup_insertado_correctamente").modal('show'); // Muestra modal si se inserto correctamente
                                  
// Aqui pienso hacer una consulta mediante ajax y hacer una condicion pero no se si sea correcto y no se como hacer la condicion paa que en caso de que ya existe no se inserte nuevamente recordando que me pidieron no cerrar la modal.          
           
                                },
                                error: function(error) {
                                    alert(error.responseText);
                                    console.log(error.responseText);
                                    jsonValue = jQuery.parseJSON(Error.responseText);
                                    alert(error.respose.Text);
                                    alert("Error");
                                }
                            });
```

Comment: Valida desde el SP que el registro no exista, en caso de existir envía un código de respuesta con el cual detectes que no se inserto por ser un duplicado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer varias cosas para evitar que se dupliquen:

- en el Ajax hay una funciona llamada `beforeSend` esta función se ejecuta justo antes de realizar el `request`, lo recomendable es que en esa función bloquees el botón aceptar para evitar que le den clicks mientras se hace el `request` y se envié doble.
- deberías manejar el estado del registro en el servidor, es decir en tu backend; allí es donde vas a validar si el `id_persona` no existe en la bd  lo creas pero si ya existe simplemente lo actualizas.
- ahora sí la tabla soporta varias veces el mismo id_persona puedes generar un `hash` con todos los datos del repuest para validar la duplicación.

Comment: Creo que la segunda recomendación @Jean Carlos García no es tan operable, la base no regresa el id hasta guardas un registro nuevo.

Comment: Ea totalmente operable y normal en la industria es conocido como upsert, de por si el ya tiene el id_persona al enviar el repuest por ese campo lo puede filtrar o bien puede generar un hash en el server pero si realmente quiere evitar la duplicación debe realizar la validación en el servidor sino será una validación blanda.

Answer (score 4):

Lo que se suele hacer en estos casos, es **deshabilitar** el botón que realiza el **Submit** (en tu caso <kbd>Aceptar</kbd>), mientras se realiza la llamada **Ajax** para agregar el registro a la base de datos.

Suponiendo que tu botón <kbd>Aceptar</kbd> tenga como identificador: **`id="IdAceptar"`**, el código sería el siguiente:

```
...

///////////////////////////////////////
// Deshabilitamos el botón de Submit //
///////////////////////////////////////
$("#IdAceptar").prop("disabled", true);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    datatype: "json",
    url: "frmPersona.aspx/Agregar_Persona",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: '{id_persona:"' + id_persona + '",nombre:"' + $("#txtNombre").val() + '",Ciudad:"' + $("#txtCiudad").val() + '"}',
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {    

        ////////////////////////////////////
        // Habilitamos el botón de Submit //
        ////////////////////////////////////
        $("#IdAceptar").prop("disabled", false);

        // Muestra modal si se inserto correctamente 
        $("#popup_insertado_correctamente").modal('show');

        // ...                                                     
    },
    error: function (error) {

        ////////////////////////////////////
        // Habilitamos el botón de Submit //
        ////////////////////////////////////
        $("#IdAceptar").prop("disabled", false);

        alert(error.responseText);
        console.log(error.responseText);
        jsonValue = jQuery.parseJSON(Error.responseText);
        alert(error.respose.Text);
        alert("Error");
    }
});

...
```